# Distorted photos on LG G2

Tags: camera, lg-g2

I've recently bought two LG G2's, and I'm having a hard time trying to get decent photos out of either of them.

The photos are distorted in a scary way.

Obvious jokes aside, look at my face in this photo (click on the photos to zoom):

[image]

And again here, with a weird line on my forehead, and smudges on the nose, mouth, etc:

[image]

Some of the photos are even worse...

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried the different modes or settings and I'm getting the same results. I keep reading the G2's camera is great, but I'm not seeing that at all...

Comment: I tried installing another camera app, and the results are much better. Is this a common problem? I have the latest update, 4.4.2.

Comment: Looking at the pictures zoomed-in, it looks like the default camera app is applying some heavy noise reduction which is reducing the number of colours in the image, causing this banding. If there's a noise reduction setting, turn it off. (I don't have this phone, so I don't know the specifics of each setting.) Otherwise, it may help to take pictures in more light so there's less noise in the first place.

Comment: @Kobi did you check what Dan recommended? Solved your issue? Then it would be nice to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), it might be helpful for others :)

Comment: @Izzy - I've added an answer, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Rewarded by 10 points rep :) I rarely use the pre-installed camera either (LG P880 here), but have 2 favorite camera apps I switch between (mostly use *A Better Camera* from Almalence recently, as my other fav, after updating the P880 to the latest stock ROM, takes 30s between "pressing the button" and "making the shot"). Option #3 would be OpenCamera, you might wish to take a look at that. For a larger selection, here's my [list of camera apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I  found is using another camera app, like [Google Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera&hl=en).

The problem is in the default LG camera app, and it still takes deformed images when I use it. I use it sometimes because it has more features and seem to take photos quicker, but I try not to take photos of people because the result can be scary and deformed.